# How do I use a function created in a parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass this `deepMap([4,5, [3,4,[2]]], x => x + 5)` into this function:

```
const deepMap = (arr, fn) => {
  return arr.reduce((first, second) => first.concat(Array.isArray(second) ? [deepMap(second)] : fn), []);  
}
```

previously it worked like this:

```
const deepMap = (arr, fn) => {
  return arr.reduce((first, second) => first.concat(Array.isArray(second) ? [deepMap(second)] : second + 5), []);  
}
```

but that didn't allow me to use the function in the second parameter. I know it needs to work like the second example, but the only way I can think to change it is like it is in the first example. I have tried numerous variations experimentally but I keep getting an error or the wrong answer.

Comment: `Array.concat` expects an array - `[second + 5]`?

Comment: Inside the `deepMap` function the function passed as an argument is named `fn`, so you call it like `fn(xyz)`. If you want subsequent recursive calls to `deepMap` to also be able to call it, you have to pass it on: `deepMap(second, fn)`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: adding fn to the call deepMap definitely helped. Thank You so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should put return value of function instead of function itself. Like this:

```
const deepMap = (arr, fn) => {
  return arr.reduce((first, second) => first.concat(Array.isArray(second) ? [deepMap(second, fn)] : fn(second)), []);  
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Inner `deepMap` should be called like `deepMap(second, fn)`, not `deepMap(second)`

Comment: Ok, fixed, Thanks wostex

Answer (score 0):

Just pass both array and function to recursive `deepMap` calls and invoke fn(cur) instead of just pointing to it.

```js
const deepMap = (arr, fn) => {
  return arr.reduce((first, second) => first.concat(Array.isArray(second) ? [deepMap(second, fn)] : fn(second)), []);  
}

const res = deepMap([4,5, [3,4,[2]]], x => x + 5);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: No explanation is not helpful

Comment: @mhodges I've added it while you were writing this comment.